# Onsubmit gets called on window.onload

Tags: javascript

first I am not JavaScript expert, just learning, trying to follow some tutorials.
What I would like JavaScript to do is, when form has been submitted do a validation on the fields.

The code I wrote so far gets triggered on page load/reload, which is not desired functionality I am after. From what I understand this formFunction should be called only on onsubmit event.
Guys if you see me something doing wrong please let me know. I would like to build a javascript function that will validate all forms on the page on submit
Here are my JavaScript steps I came up with so far:

1 call checkForms function on window.onload

```
window.onload=checkForms;
```

2 loop through all forms on the page and add onsubmit listener for the page forms

```
function checkForms(){
    for(var i=0; i<document.forms.length; i++){
        document.forms[i].onsubmit=thisForm(document.forms[i]);
    }
}
```

3 trigger thisForm function on submit

```
function thisForm(thisForm){
    var elements = thisForm.elements;
    var msg='';
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        msg += elements[i].name +'\n';
    }
    alert(msg);
    // this is where I want to send field values to be validated
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is your problem:

```
document.forms[i].onsubmit=thisForm(document.forms[i]);
```

You're calling thisForm() instead of setting it as function reference.  The easiest thing to do is to make a closure:

```
document.forms[i].onsubmit=function(){thisForm(document.forms[i])};
```

Comment: When i change the code as per your suggestion, on page load it is not triggering the function, but when i am submitting the form also nothing happening. Where am i going wrong? Thank you.